# Tawheed Concepts

Tags: allah, life, tawheed

What is it that Muslims understand of the ‘nature of human’, the ‘purpose of human life’, and the ‘meaning of human life’.

Comment: This question does not meet our quality standards. Please edit your question to focus on one only. And create separate questions for others. For more information on how to ask a question well, please see our [How to Ask guide](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: OK. Edited the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked some very fundamental questions and I would try and answer in brief, hoping that that wouldn't be the end of your quest for the meaning of life.

**Nature of human**
You probably meant "nature of man" here. In the Qur'an, man is described as the 'noblest' of God's creation. Man can ascend to the heights of the angels, and he can descend below the animals.

> [Qur'an 95:4-6](http://quran.com/95/4-6) We have certainly created man in the best of
>   stature and then We returned him to the lowest of the low, with the
>   exception of those who believe and do righteous deeds, for they will
>   have a reward uninterrupted.

Man has been given free will by God to either believe in Him or not believe. He has also been created to have base desires and lofty ones. While man can be very selfish and wicked, he is also able to be generous and heroic. His success is in how much he's able to master his base desires in the service of God.

**Purpose and meaning of Human Life**
Several verses of the Qur'an speak on man's purpose. Any careful observer of the natural world would see that although man shares many traits with other animals, he's significantly different. It's only him that can think, speak and improve himself.

> [Qur'an 23:78](http://quran.com/23/78/)
>   He it is Who hath created for you ears and eyes and hearts. Small
>   thanks give ye!

His superiority over the rest of the creatures is in how much he uses these faculties, otherwise he's no better than cattle:

> [Qur'an 8:22](http://quran.com/8/22)
>   Indeed, the worst of living creatures in the sight of Allah are the deaf and dumb who do not use reason.

The inquisitive person must ask himself why man is so different. Some dismiss life as a mechanical process that means nothing. They conceive the universe as a ship without a captain, or even if there was a captain, they're not bothered. However, the question of why still remains. Many people are thrown into depression because they can't understand how their suffering is of no consequence.

In Islam, there is a worldly life and an afterlife. The worldly life is meant to serve as a path to the eternal afterlife. In the worldly life, man is subjected to tests and trials while in the afterlife he shall be called into account with regards to all his deeds:

> [Qur'an 18:49](http://quran.com/18/49)
>   And the Book (of Deeds) will be placed (before you); and thou wilt see
>   the sinful in great terror because of what is (recorded) therein; they
>   will say, "Ah! woe to us! what a Book is this! It leaves out nothing
>   small or great, but takes account thereof!" They will find all that
>   they did, placed before them: And not one will thy Lord treat with
>   injustice.

The purpose of man in this life is to worship his Maker as much as he is able knowing that he will meet Him someday. For this reason, God has sent several warners, culminating in Muhammad (peace be upon him), so as to guide mankind to His commandments and guide them to the right path.